# sending an email in android ...

Tags: email, android-emulator, android-intent

I am trying to send an email from my app.
the code goes lik this :

```
Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
i.setType("text/plain");
i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL  , new String[]{"recipient@gmail.com"});
i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "subject of email");
i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT   , "body of email");
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(i, "Send mail..."));
```

in the emulator it shows the email client again i have to enter the recipient address, when i click send button it doesnt send .[image]

and it is showing the messaging(MMS) context.

any help is highly appreciated ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here the problem was the email client was not configured in the emulator,,, 
It works fine in the device ...